# Predefined range of variables task

Tags: c++, function, equation

Can somebody explain me this task:
*Write a function whose call will print the solutions of the equation for a predefined range of variables. The function should have two parameters, the beginning and the end of the range, and the equation for which solutions are sought is:
x ^ 2 + 2x - 5
Test function operation for x belongs to [0.5].*

Answer (score 0):

I guess they expect something like that:

```
void solve(std::pair<float*, float*> range, const std::vector<float>& polynomCoeffs) {
  for (auto it = range.first; it != range.second; ++it) {
    // solve and std::cout the thing
  }
}
```

and call it this way

```
float values[] = { 0.f, 42.f, -100.f };
std::vector<float> coeffs = { 1, 2, -5 };

solve(std::make_pair(std::begin(values), std::end(values)), coeffs);
```

Comment: and where exactly the equation  x ^ 2 + 2x - 5 is used ?

Comment: In the for loop. You have your x (`*it`)  and your a/b/c (`polynomCoeffs[0..2]`) . Just "solve for x" and print out the result.

Comment: how do I test this function for x=0.5 and what should I print out ? Sorry but it ain't clear to me...

Comment: I've read that "x belongs to [0.5]" as x = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } but maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: What's the point of having a range of 1 element?

Comment: I should test this function for x = 0.5 it ain't permanent value of x